# Simple HTML Dom Parser, More Woes

Tags: php, html, dom, parsing

I am making use of the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to get the number 3869 from a HTML page. I tried this and a few other variations.

```
foreach($html->find('span[class=searchresults_tab_number]') as $element) {
            echo $element->innertext . '<br />';
}
```

But I keep getting nothing returned! All I need is the number from set1, how can I match this?

```
<div class="local-tabs">
    <div class="local-tab active">Set1 <span class="searchresults_tab_number">(3869)</span></div>
    <div class="local-tab"><a href="#">Set2 <span class="searchresults_tab_number">(1)</span></a></div>
    <div class="local-tab"><a href="#">Set3 <span class="searchresults_tab_number">(3870)</span></a></div>
</div>
```

Thanks all for any help

### Update

I just realised that those elements are created via javascript, does this make a difference?

```
tabs.insert("<div class='local-tab active'>Set1 <span class='searchresults_tab_number'>(3869)</span></div>");
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" ? There are a few of them - and it looks like you're trying to use SimpleXML, but as far as I know, that doesn't come with a find() method.

Comment: I am making use of this: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm

Comment: What does `print_r($html->find('span[class=searchresults_tab_number]'));` show? Your code seems valid to me.

Comment: Ah, awesome - didn't know about that class. Looking into it now :)

Comment: @Daniel it just shows a `Array ()`. An empty array?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javascript is not executed when scraping a page, so php cannot scrape for it if it is being generated with javascript.  javascript is executed by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

http://gist.github.com/488815

The above gist seems to be working fine, I get the output one would expect. Could it be something wrong with the code before it? Do you have a more complete sample?

In reply to updated question: I'm very confused as to what you're doing... where does PHP gets its DOM from? If the divs are created in Javascript, PHP won't know about them. It does not execute the javascript that is part of HTML content.

Comment: The php parser is separate to the HTML page it is parsing. So my PHP parser makes use of a `file_get_html` so the html page is loaded and then it tries to parse it, but the html page makes use of Javascript to create some elements which I would of thought the parser should have access to.

Comment: if the javascript is on the page (as opposed to a script include), php has access to the javascript on the page, yes. But as arbitrary text.  php doesn't actually execute the javascript on the page, so the div is never built.  The php DOM is a static DOM, not a live DOM. 

So if the javascript is physically on the page, you can use regex to parse out the raw info you need.